# Group generated by symmetric shears

Tags: gr.group-theory, matrices

Consider the multiplicative group generated by matrices of the form 
$$
\begin{bmatrix} 
  {1} & { 0}  & { c_1} & {c_3}  \\
  {0} & {1}  & {c_3} & {c_2} \\
  {0} & {0}  & {1} & {0} \\
  {0} & {0}  & {0} & {1}
\end{bmatrix}
$$

along with their transposes 
$$
\begin{bmatrix} 
  {1} & { 0}  & {0} & {0}  \\
  {0} & {1}  & {0} & {0} \\
  {c_4} & {c_6}  & {1} & {0} \\
  {c_6} & {c_5}  & {0} & {1}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
where $c_i \in \mathbb{R}.$ Is there any easier way to describe this group, e.g. by identifying it with one of the more typical matrix groups?

More generally we can consider groups generated by matrices of the form 
$$
\begin{bmatrix} 
  {I_n} & {C}\\
  {0} & {I_n}\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
and their transposes, where $C$ is symmetric. Is there any better way to describe these groups?

Comment: I didn't look into it much but it seems plausible that your group is just the full special linear group. Can you exclude that, and if not did you try to prove it?